# Django template - inline POST as hyperlink logic

Tags: django, templates

I have a simple yet frustrating problem:

in my template I have:

```
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}

    {% if lang.0 != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}">
        <a href=# onclick="submitPostLink()">{{ lang.1 }}</a> |
    {% else %}
        {{ lang.1 }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The language switching works fine, it's just that the pipe separator which I want to separate the two languages which can be selected doesn't stay in the middle. Obviously when the first statement is evaluated to false in the first instance then the linked option is written last and the pipe appears at the end. Does anyone have a simple way to get a pipe separator fixed in between the two on both conditions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try using the [forloop counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for)...? ...not to write the separator in the last item

```
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}

    {% if lang.0 != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}">
        <a href=# onclick="submitPostLink()">{{ lang.1 }}</a>
    {% else %}
        {{ lang.1 }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if forloop.last != true %}
     |
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Good idea. However, this results in a pipe after each language option.

Comment: And weirdly, `{% if forloop.first == true %} | {% endif %}` results in no pipe.

Comment: could you post how the language menu should look like (like link | active link | link ?), not sure if I grasped the point

Comment: it really is just two options at the moment: `English | Español` The `LANGUAGES` tuple will always return English as the first option, but obviously the active link could be written first or second (wherein lies the problem).